Null Pointer Exception in AdjustPosition method of KeyboardAutoScrollManager when using full-screen modal view controller in Maui
I'm encountering a null pointer exception in the AdjustPosition method of KeyboardAutoScrollManager while testing a plugin with a third-party SDK for UI presentation. This issue arises when presenting a full-screen modal view controller containing text fields. How can I fix this problem?

I've encountered and resolved this issue after some extensive troubleshooting. I noticed a few related bug reports opened at:
GitHub Issue 21160
Microsoft Q&A Thread
My workaround involves disconnecting before the page opens:
     #if IOS
      KeyboardAutoManagerScroll.Disconnect();
 #endif

 await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page,false);

And then reconnecting after the page has opened and initialized:
            InitializeComponent();
          

#if IOS

            KeyboardAutoManagerScroll.Connect();
#endif

